# Merge several text boxes into one slide for iphone

Tags: iphone

I have all my labels and textfields together on one slide , that I want to combine or merge for example each three of them into one slide (Dunno If that is clear for you guys but I hope u understand what I mean by that ) 
So, is there any method or function to help me work that out ?

thanks in advance

Comment: well, all my labels and textfields have been displayed into one view and I want to seperate them and merge for example each three of them

Comment: I think you need to rewrite your question because it's really unclear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I symply wanna know how to combine three attributes for example; first name, family name, adresse to one group together and do the same for the rest of the attributes

Comment: One group visually as in combine them in one view? or store the values together in one group?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are asking, but if you are saying you want to take 3 input fields and store them in an object, you will want to grab the text values of each of your text fields in the controller and place them in your model objects.